# Modify MDN tutorial to make WebRTC one-to-many calls

Tags: javascript, webrtc

It is August 2020 and I am new to WebRTC.  I have followed the instructions found [here](https://github.com/mdn/samples-server/tree/master/s/webrtc-from-chat) and have successfully made both video and audio only calls with some additions to the code.

What I am having trouble about is modifying this code to make one-to-many or even many-to-many calls - video and audio only.

What I have started with so far is to replace [0] with [i]:

```
function handleTrackEvent(event) {
    document.getElementById("received_video").srcObject = event.streams[0];
    document.getElementById("hangup-button").disabled = false;
}

function handleTrackEvent(event, i) {
    document.getElementById("received_video").srcObject = event.streams[i];
    document.getElementById("hangup-button").disabled = false;
}
```

and initiate i at:

```
function handleUserlistMsg(msg) {
    var i = 0;
    var listElem = document.querySelector(".userlistbox");

    while (listElem.firstChild) {
        listElem.removeChild(listElem.firstChild);
    }

    msg.users.forEach(function(username) {
        var item = document.createElement("li");
        item.appendChild(document.createTextNode(username));
        item.addEventListener("click", invite(event, i), false);
        listElem.appendChild(item);
        i++;
    });
}
```

The problem I am running into in the console log is:

```
[10:00:17 AM] Error InvalidStateError: Failed to execute 'setRemoteDescription' 

on 'RTCPeerConnection': Failed to set remote answer sdp: Called in wrong state: kStable
```

which to me says that I already have a connection to a peer

So, how do I make multiple connections one caller initiating many participants?

Comment: i think you need to connect to a server and the service relays it to multiple clients

Comment: Yeah I hadn't thought of that - I am connecting to a server - but Ineed to make the server do the connecting, not the client.   all the code I posted is client-side.  Thanks @Daniel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my solution to this problem was solved by scrapping the raw webRTC and using https://jitsi.org
This software is private, customizable and reliable on my own server.